# Faux Mordell equation and positive binary quadratic forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

This is about the frequency of integral solutions to
$$  b^2 - 4 a^3 = \Delta,  $$
when $\Delta < 0$ is a discriminant of positive binary quadratic forms such that the class number is divisible by 3. My observation is that integral solutions are pretty frequent when $|\Delta|$ is small. For instance, there are 25 discriminants with class number exactly 3. Of these, in 19 cases we can write the non-principal, order three form as $$ \langle a, \pm b, a^2  \rangle,  $$ the failures seeming to be $$ \Delta = -124, \; -172, \; -307, \; -547, \; -652, \; 907,$$ with the first two proved impossible in integers, maybe all six.

Note that there may be multiple solutions for a given $\Delta,$ which usually means the forms reduce to the same thing or the principal form, as in
$$  \langle 2, 1, 4  \rangle =  \langle 4, 15, 16  \rangle   $$  but
$$   \langle 10, 63, 100  \rangle =   \langle 1, 1, 8  \rangle. $$ 
On the other hand, in the relatively rare event of 3-rank larger than one, we may have genuinely distinct cube roots of 1, and for $\Delta = -3299$  we find
$$   \langle 11,45, 121  \rangle =   \langle 11, 1, 75  \rangle, $$
$$   \langle 15, 101, 225  \rangle =   \langle 15, 11, 57  \rangle, $$
$$   \langle 23, 213, 529  \rangle =   \langle 23, -17, 39  \rangle. $$

So, the question is, how likely is it that a positive form of order three in the class group can be written as
$$ f(x,y) = a x^2 + b x y + a^2 y^2 ?  $$

EDIT: of course this becomes Mordell's equation when $\Delta$ is even, which is how I know there are proofs for $-124, -172$ but a rational solution $a = 1177/36, \; b = 40355/108$ for $-172.$ Hope I got the factor of 2 in the right place.

EDIT TOOOOO: forgot. by Dirichlet's "united forms" description of composition, 
$$   \langle a,b,a^2  \rangle^2 =   \langle a^2, b,a  \rangle, $$ so such a form is either the principal form or of order three, as long as $$ \gcd(a,b) = 1.  $$

EDIT THREE, Saturday: The importance of this for my other recent questions appeared when I found that $ \langle 4,1,9  \rangle$ integrally represents 77, but $ \langle 4,1,9  \rangle + \langle 4,1,9  \rangle,$ or $g(x,y,z,w) = 4 x^2 + x y + 9 y^2 + 4 z^2 + z w + 9 w^2,$ does not represent $77^2 = 5929.$ Now,  $ \langle 4,1,9  \rangle$ has order five, so the set of values it represents is not required to be multiplicative. Similarly, if $f$ is of order 2 "ambiguous," it seems always true that $f$ represents some $n$ (often prime) while $f(x,y) + f(z,w)$ fails to represent $n^2.$ Note that the original form in question 
 [88905](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88905/a-quadratic-form-represents-all-primes-except-for-the-primes-2-and-11)  is of order three, indeed 
$$  \langle 4,2, 3  \rangle =  \langle 3,-2,4  \rangle  =  \langle 3,-8,9  \rangle.  $$
So three seems to be the order of the day.

Comment: P. S. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_for_the_orders_of_the_day and http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/order+of+the+day  . Also, Mordell's wife was named Mabel rather than Faux, http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Mordell.html 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you treat $b^2-4a^3=\Delta$ as an elliptic curve, say $E_\Delta$, then of course there are only finitely many integer  points on $E_\Delta$ (effectively by Baker). But since you're interested in the *number* of solutions, then possibly it's useful to know that under the assumption that $\Delta$ is 6'th power free,  there exists an *absolute* constant $C$ such that
$$\#E_\Delta(\mathbb{Z})\le C^{1+\hbox{rank }E_\Delta(\mathbb{Q})}.$$ [*J. Reine angew. Math* **378** (1987), 60-100.] Actually, you can probably relax the 6'th power free assumption on $\Delta$ if you restrict to integer solutions such that $\gcd(a^2,b^3)$ is 6'th power free.

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I realized at some point that there were various possible subquestions, and that I may not have hit quite the right note. As $n \rightarrow -\infty,$ both the count of possible values of $0 \geq b^2 - 4 a^3 \geq n$ and the number of discriminants with class number divisible by 3 with  $0 \geq \Delta \geq n$ go to infinity. What I had in mind was, given class number divisible by 3, is there a nonzero likelihood that there is any solution at all to 
$b^2 - 4 a^3 = \Delta?$ I admit, this does not end things, for example you may just be rewriting the principal form...

Comment: @W.Jagy: On average one expects zero integral solutions as $|\Delta| \rightarrow \infty$, and I think this can be proved under the ABC conjecture, or just Hall's conjecture; more precisely, there should be only $O(n^{5/6 + \epsilon})$ solutions of $|b^2 - 4a^3| \leq n$ (and it's easy to show the number of solutions is $\gg n^{5/6}$).  